# Excel - Looping through data till it finds the right one

Tags: excel, lookup, formula

I'm pulling data from one Excel table into another using an IF statement. I want it to check two fields and if it is a match I want it to print something and if it doesn't then I want it to continue searching. If there is no absolute match then leave the field blank.

I believe I'm running into an syntax issue but after numerous iterations I can't get it to pull everything over. Here is my current syntax.

```
=IF(BM5<>"External","",IF(AND(S5=VLOOKUP(A5,ExternalOnly,5,FALSE),A5=VLOOKUP(A5,ExternalOnly,1,FALSE)),S5,"")
```

Comment: Put code sample around your code example please.

Answer (score 1):

Add an additional ')' at the end of the formula and see if this works.

i.e. 
try this

=IF(BM5<>"External","",IF(AND(S5=VLOOKUP(A5,ExternalOnly,5,FALSE),A5=VLOOKUP(A5,ExternalOnly,1,FALSE)),S5,""))

Comment: Formula running wasn't my problem. What was wrong was that it would not continue to search beyond the first hit.
i.e. John Smith shows 12 times w/ 12 different $ amts but I can't get it to look beyond the first instance of John Smith. That's why I was trying the AND stmt.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

INDEX($E$1:$E$7,MATCH(A7,$D$1:$D$7,0))

Here is a sample table to illustrate. the formula is in the cells of column B (B7 in this case).  How it works is the match finds the corresponding entry in the target list ($D$1:$D$7) for our selected value (A7). It returns the index from that list and the INDEX() function lets us select a different column from the matched row to return.

```
A         B      C     D       E
------    ---   ---    ------  ---
011597  99          012062  3
012062  3           012142  8
012136  3           011597  99
012142  8           012136  3
014157  2           014157  2
011582  87          011582  87
011707  101         011707  101
```

Comment: Hey Kelly my list is more like this:
   A      B    C      D    E       F    G    H
 1 011597 99   J5          012062  3    J5
 2 012062 9    J5          012142  8    Z6
 3 012062 3    T90         012136  44   B9

I'm trying for a formula that would search Range A1:C3 for what is in E1 and F1 & when a match was found print in cell H1 the results from C. In the example above H1 would be populated with "T90". H2 & H3 would be blank.

Comment: @DanoK: can you edit your question and add the sample list from your comment? That way you can get the columns to line up better and it'll be easier to read